# Which data storage method should I use for back-end admin to an APP

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am making an App that has annotations on the Map based on locations people have taken photographs of.  Once the App has been developed and is deployed on the client's iPad I would like them to have the ability to ADD locations when they visit somewhere new.  I would also like them to be able to add the pictures they have taken and perhaps some comments about the place.

The question is, how can I allow the user to upload new content and new locations (coordinates) so that new annotations appear on the map, with new photos of the place, and new  details of the locations.  I already have the app with existing annotations, and a detailDisclosureButton that once pressed loads a view with detailed information.  I just need a way for the client to be able to add new locations and information and have that upload to the App.

Would iCloud somehow serve this purpose? Or should I be using Core Data and have a way for the client to simply add new photos an info to a server, which then connects to my App and updates it via Core Data? What about simply using MSMutableArrays...can these be connected to a server for updates? Or perhaps SqlLite?

Any ideas on where to start?  Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do similar things in our app.  We have a sqlite database on the app, but we back it up to our own servers and sync the two periodically.  The iCloud should be able to do this, but our apps can sync with Android devices or a web app as well, so we use our own servers.

Having it in a sqlite database on app really helps for performance.  Having it backed up off of the device really helps the user experience, in case they change devices, reset their device, etc.

So we let our users add information, and if they are online, we push that information up to our server.  Then periodically, we check our server to see if there are any data updates to push down to them, as we let them have their same account on multiple devices.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!  I wasnt even thinking about other devices which will be something I will be developing shortly so great call on that point too!

Comment: One more thing...as I understand it, I would need to set-up a mySQl database on a PHP page for the web server .... and have this data coordinate with my SQLite database on the app. So is the mySQL/SQLite combination considered the best way to push data from a server to an App?